# Importing Data into Simulink Block Diagrams Issue

Tags: arrays, matlab, time, import, simulink

To all MATLAB and Simulink users,

I am doing a project and faced a problem importing data from a 'Signal From Workspace' in Simulink block.

**My case:**

I need to input 565 rows of 2 columns of data over a sample period of 22seconds into my Simulink block diagram. Each data sample time is 22/565.

However, the output data is a [565 x 2] which affects the input to the downstream Simulink blocks due to dimensions issue.

For example, Ideally, [1 x 2] output multiplies with [2 x 1] and repeat for 565 times over 22 seconds. Now, [565 x 2] output signal couldn't get through due to the dimension.

**My attempts to solve the problem:**

I tried using 'From workspace' instead of 'Signal From Workspace' but face some problems.

t=[0:22/565:22]' M (565 rows n 2 columns of values) data.time=t; data.signals.values = M; data.signals.dimensions=[565 2];

**This error pops up when simulation is run:**

*"Invalid structure-format variable specified as workspace input in 'test/From Workspace'. The structure 'dimensions'field must be a scalar or a vector with 2 elements. In addition, this field must be compatible with the dimensions of input signal stored in the 'values' field. " *

I greatly appreciate if anybody can provide insight/solutions/alternative method to my case.

THANK YOU!

Regards, 
KO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you should be using

```
data.signals.dimensions = 2;
```

For example

```
>> t= linspace(0,10,1001)';
>> data.time = t;
>> data.signals.values = [sin(t) cos(t)];
>> data.signals.dimensions = 2;
```

Comment: Hi Phil Goddard, how do I determine the dimensions? if 500 rows and 2 columns [500 2], the dimension equals to 500x2=1000? Right?

Comment: No, 1000 is the number of elements of data, not the dimensions of it.  Assuming you are using "sample based" data then you have 2 signals (one in each column) which is why the dimension is 2.